# How do you print out object elements in an object array?

Tags: java, arrays

Here are my two arrays, one a color array which contains another color array as elements and the second one an object array which contains another object array as its elements.

```
Color[] colourArray= {colorBase[1], colorBase[2], colorBase[2], colorBase[6],colorBase[5], colorBase[0]};


Ball[] objectArray = {ballGrid[1], ballGrid[2], ballGrid2[2], ballGrid[6], ballGrid[5], ballGrid2[0]};
```

In my program, I check the Color array which returns which which element is true, and then I want to print out the same element from the Ball array.

For example, if colorArray[4] (colorBase[5]) is true, then the program should print out objectArray[4] which is "ballGrid[5]".

```
if(colorArray[4]==Color.blue){              
    System.out.println((objectArray[4].toString()));
}
```

However the output is [finalproject.Ball@9aba32], but I need it to be ballGrid[5].

How would you do that?

I tried Arrays.deeptoString but it produced the same result and also overriding toString() in the Ball class but it doesn't work for my case.

Comment: "_one a color array which contains another color array as elements_" If you are saying that `colorBase[1]` is an array, I think you've got this wrong. Since you are referencing an index of an array you are getting the element at that position, not a whole array. Maybe you meant to create a new array at each location like `{new colorBase[1]}`

Comment: you are getting the element at a particular index which is another object hence hashcode it returned. override the toString() correctly in ball class  and return the string object

Comment: Praveen's comment is the answer, I will suppose.

Answer (score 0):

No, It is not possible, since you are storing the values of another array in an array using the index. To make it clear

Here you are using if`(colorArray[4]==Color.blue)` , `colorArray[4]` refers to `colorBase[5]` which inturn gets the 5th index value(Color object) stored in colorBase array and returned, but not the `colorBase[5]` itself.

Similarly when you access `objectArray[4]` you get Ball object stored at 5th index of ballgrid array, but not `ballGrid[5]`

So you get *ballGrid[5]* unless you store this as a String directly, but that is not what you meant in the array declaration.